# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2). TransformerEncoder

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

Trying out different models and for some reason I keep getting this error after trying to change everything I can. Can somebody explain where my fault is here or show me how to fix this issue?

I am doing this on mnist_1d dataset.

Model code:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        from torch.nn import TransformerEncoder, TransformerEncoderLayer
        encoder_layers = TransformerEncoderLayer(40, 8)
        self.transformer_encoder = TransformerEncoder(encoder_layers, 6)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(40, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.transformer_encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

Training code:

```
import torch.optim as optim

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(3):
    for data in trainset:
        X, y = data
        print(X.view(-1, 40).shape)
        net.zero_grad()
        output = net(X.view(-1,40))
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Error message:

```
torch.Size([1, 40])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-53cd1214bd32> in <module>()
      5         net.zero_grad()
----> 6         output = net(X.view(-1,40))
      7         loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)

<ipython-input-13-fd44a15921d2> in forward(self, x)
      8 
      9     def forward(self, x):
---> 10         x = self.transformer_encoder(x)
     11         x = self.decoder(x)
     12         return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/activation.py in forward(self, query, key, value, key_padding_mask, need_weights, attn_mask)
    983                 training=self.training,
    984                 key_padding_mask=key_padding_mask, need_weights=need_weights,
--> 985                 attn_mask=attn_mask)
    986 
    987 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in multi_head_attention_forward(query, key, value, embed_dim_to_check, num_heads, in_proj_weight, in_proj_bias, bias_k, bias_v, add_zero_attn, dropout_p, out_proj_weight, out_proj_bias, training, key_padding_mask, need_weights, attn_mask, use_separate_proj_weight, q_proj_weight, k_proj_weight, v_proj_weight, static_k, static_v)
   4132                 q_proj_weight=q_proj_weight, k_proj_weight=k_proj_weight,
   4133                 v_proj_weight=v_proj_weight, static_k=static_k, static_v=static_v)
-> 4134     tgt_len, bsz, embed_dim = query.size()
   4135     assert embed_dim == embed_dim_to_check
   4136     # allow MHA to have different sizes for the feature dimension

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Could not post the entire error message

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deconstruct `query.size()` into values `tgt_len`, `bsz`, `embed_dim`, i.e. you are assuming that query is a three-dimensional tensor.

Python complains that it was expecting three values, but got 2. In other words, `query` is a two-dimensional tensor, which is no surprise, as you reshape your input `X` to shape `(-1, 30)`.

Read through the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html#torch.nn.Transformer) of the pytorch transformer class and reshape your inputs accordingly.